# Use anchor with parallax scrolling

Tags: css, anchor, parallax

I'm trying to create a vertical bullet navigator for a website with parallax scrolling. Unfortunately the redirect of the nav isn't working.

here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r1yq7pLd/

Scrolling seems ok but the anchor doesn't work. Anyone knows the reason?
html:

```
<div id="wrapper">


        <section id="main_bg" data-type="background" data-speed="10">
            <a href="#top"></a>

        </section>

        <section class="content" data-type="text">

            <article><a href="#pag2"></a>I am absolute positioned</article>
        </section>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#top">&bull;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#pag2">&bull;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">&bull;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">&bull;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">&bull;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">&bull;</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

css:
    body{
        background-color:#1599D0;
    }

```
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height: 1000px;
}

nav{
    top: 35%;
    position: fixed;
    right: 50px;
    width: 30px;
    border-left: double rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    border-right: double rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}


ul li a{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

#main_bg{
  background: url("../img/wall_index1.jpg") repeat fixed;
  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size:cover;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: relative;

}

.content{
    position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#000;
  padding: 200px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Note: the menu here is a bit messy due absence of reset.css. Is it possible to insert it in jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes, you can include external CSS files in jsFiddle - on the left hand side of the screen is the External Resources buttton, insert it there.

Comment: @Andi - No it doesn't.

Comment: I've only tested "top". And this is working. But not because of the correct anchor, but because of loading the page with #top, which will start, of course, at the top. To fast response from me.

Comment: Yes, that sort of works accidentally.

Answer (score 3):

It's not to do with the CSS you're using, it's because you've not set your anchors properly. `Pag2` and `Top` are should be set as `id`s, with the navigation using `href` to link back to them - you have both set as `href`. Also, you don't need to actually set separate anchors anymore, you can just use `id`s within your existing elements. Finally, exclude the hash from the `id` itself, that's just to tell the link to look for an anchor rather than a new page.

Your html should be:

```
<div id="wrapper">

        <section id="main_bg" data-type="background" data-speed="10"></section>

        <section class="content" data-type="text">
             <article id="pag2">I am absolute positioned</article>
        </section>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Top</a></li>
                <li><a href="#pag2">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">...other links</a></li>
                <li><a href="">...other links</a></li>
                <li><a href="">...other links</a></li>    
            </ul>
        </nav>
</div>
```

There's no need for separate top anchor, "#" will always go to the top of the current page.

Incidentally, I'm not sure why you've got bullets within your list - by default, an unordered list (`<ul>`) will put bullets in for you, so I've replaced your link text with something more meaningful.